# Parts of For Loop not firing in Order

Tags: javascript, angular

Using Angular 5, I have created a function that gets data from a web request. Based on the data received from the request, I have a second web request firing based on the received `System.Title`. However, the function is firing the parts of the first loop and waiting to fire the second loop until the end of the first loop. How can I fix this?

Here is the TS:

```
selectedDocType(title){    
    this.http.get("https://test.com/items?$select=Title,Image,Source/Title,System/Title&$filter=Title eq '" + title + "'").subscribe(data => {

      for (let i = 0; i < data['value'].length; i++) {
          let system = data['value'][i].System.Title;

          // REVIEW: FIRING AT END OF MAIN LOOP
          this.http.get("https://test.com/items?$select=Title,Location,Image&$filter=Title eq '" + system + "'").subscribe(data => {

            for (let i = 0; i < data['value'].length; i++) {
                var systemlocation = data['value'][i].Location;
                this.location = data['value'][i].Location;
                console.log("this.location", this.location)  // REVIEW: LAST LOG IN CONSOLE; DEFINED CORRECTLY
            }
          });

        let sources = data['value'][i].Source;
        for (let i = 0; i < sources.length; i++) {
            console.log("this.location", this.location) // REVIEW: UNDEFINED    
        };
        console.log("at end of main loop") // REVIEW: FIRES BEFORE LAST LOG
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: anything that uses the data returned from the request (such as location) should be inside that requests callback function.